# Wordpress Custom Meta not saving Paragraphs

Tags: php, wordpress

Can anyone see anything wrong with the below.

http://pastebin.com/cqrqs35Z

None of my paragraphs are either saving or echoing out. Ive looked around and most people have the problem of showing the breaks on the front end where as mine dont seem to show on either.

Update after mod put the question on hold. 
My problem is that I have a custom meta box for adding content in the wordpress custom post type (apartments). 
I want this meta data to be able to be saved in cluding paragraphs and formatting. 
The editor is a WYSIWYG editor and is capable of adding content formatting such as line breaks, heading etc. 
When the post is saved, none of the formatting is retained in the post meta data thus no formatting shown on the front end. 
My question is whilst I have seen many different applications, this seems pretty standard and I would ask someone to pass a fresh look over the code and see if they can see any reason it isnt working.

Comment: is `apartmentterms_sectionid` is your post type

Comment: No, the $screens variable is on line 12

Comment: Do you mean that paragraph <p> or line-breaks not working ? or your actual text is not being displayed?

Answer (score 3):

**Try This Code  :**

```
function register_vidopress_metabox() {
    add_meta_box( 'frankly_Video_Blog_meta_box', // Yor meta box name 
            'Add Video',                         // your Metabox Title
            'add_frankly_Video_Blog_meta_box', // Metabox callback
            'video_blog',                        // Post Type
          'normal', 'high'
        );
}
```

**Add Hook**

```
add_action( 'admin_init', 'register_vidopress_metabox' );
```

**Call BAck Function**

```
function add_frankly_Video_Blog_meta_box($video_blog){

    ?>
<table >

    <tr>
        <td><label class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 col-md-3 col-lg-2">Need Video Comment :</label></td>
        <td><input type="hidden" name="need_video_comment" value="">
        <input class="video_checkbox" type="checkbox" name="need_video_comment" <?php echo (get_post_meta($video_blog->ID,'need_video_comment',true)=='on'? 'checked' : '');?>  id="need_video_comment"></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td><label class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 col-md-3 col-lg-2">Display Ask me Widget :</label></td>
        <td><input type="hidden" name="need_askme" value="">
        <input class="video_checkbox" type="checkbox" name="need_askme" <?php echo (get_post_meta($video_blog->ID,'need_askme',true)=='on' ? 'checked' : '');?> id="need_askme"></td>
    </tr>

    <!-- <tr>
        <td><label class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 col-md-3 col-lg-2">Display Intro Video :</label></td>
        <td><input type="hidden" name="need_itro" value="">
        <input class="video_checkbox" type="checkbox" name="need_itro" <?php // echo (get_post_meta($video_blog->ID,'need_itro',true)=='on' ? 'checked' : '');?> id="need_itro"></td>
    </tr> -->

</table>
<?php 
}
```

I am Just Sharing My Working Code .

Comment: Thanks dude but this is well outside the wp_editor function im looking for help with.

Comment: do you want to add another editor outside the wp_editor ???